# Converting a list that contains integers and strings into a nested tuple, Python

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I wish to convert a string into a nested tuple for instance:

```
string = 'Jane A 3 B- 3 F 1#Bob C+ 2 D+ 3#Chris C 4 C 3 C- 2'
```

As you can see, the string is not normal with **#** signs and white-spaces in place of a comma. The **#** sign is what represents the number of names for which I have to compute some data that follows after each name. So I used `string.split('#')` to create 3 separate strings and from there, I used a for loop to get this on the first iteration:

```
['A', 3, 'B-', 3, 'F', 1]
```

The reason why 'Jane' is missing from the list is because I only need to take the values, whether it be a string or an integer, and make a nested tuple out of them. Thus, I wish to convert this list into a nested tuple that looks like:

```
[('A', 3), ('B-', 3), ('F', 1)]
```

I will greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: what does `A/B/C/D` with `+`/`-` mean? and a number after it?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is a better way, but here we go:

```
input = ['A', 3, 'B-', 3, 'F', 1]

l1 = input[::2] # get even
l2 = input[1::2] # get odd

tuples = list(zip(l1,l2)) # zip them together
# yes it could be wrote `tuples = list(zip(input[::2],input[1::2]))`

print (tuples)
```

Output

```
[('A', 3), ('B-', 3), ('F', 1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzOvoLREwVYhWt1RXUfBWEdB3UkXynAD0oaxXFw5hkB5sLpoKyujWK4cIzjfECzAVVJakJNaDBTNySwu0ajKLNDIMdTJMdLU5OIqKMrMK1HQgKjQ/P8fAA)

Answer (score 0):

using [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info)

```
>>> import re
>>> [[(mark, int(count))
      for mark, count in map(str.split,
                             re.findall(r'[A-Z][+-]? \d+', student_data))]
     for student_data in string.split('#')]
[[('A', 3), ('B-', 3), ('F', 1)],
 [('C+', 2), ('D+', 3)],
 [('C', 4), ('C', 3), ('C-', 2)]]
```

## Step-by-step explanation

1. We're separating students (let's call them so) from each other since we need to store their "marks" (or what does these `A`/`B`/`C`/`D` with `+`/`-` mean?) in different containers:

   ```
   string.split('#')
   ```
2. For each student we're searching "mark" data using regular expression

   ```
   [A-Z][+-]? \d+
   ```

   which can be read like

   > any capital Latin letter (which optionally may be followed by `+` or `-` sign) and a whitespace followed by digits

   and pass it and student's substring to `re.findall` function. After that we will have something like:

   ```
   >>> [re.findall(r'[A-Z][+-]? \d', student_data) for student_data in string.split('#')]
   [['A 3', 'B- 3', 'F 1'], ['C+ 2', 'D+ 3'], ['C 4', 'C 3', 'C- 2']]
   ```
3. Finally we can use `str.split` method to separate letters with `+`/`-` from digits and iterate over this pairs converting second coordinates to `int`.

## Further reading

- [`map` built-in docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map).
- [`re` module docs](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Comment: Yes the +/- signs are letter grades and I need to write a function that takes a weird string and determines whether any of the students in the list make the dean's list. So far I have around 64 lines of code with proper spacing between functions but it doesn't work. What I mean is that I use a helper function to determine their gpa which takes a tuple as its argument. When I input the tuples from my string manually, it gives the right answer but when I try to return it in my program with the string function included, I get an error.

Comment: I think you would understand what I mean if you saw my code. I know what I am supposed to do but I think its something really trivial that I'm missing. If you can help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I had a previous assignment where I had to write a function that took a list of tuples and use a dictionary to determine the overall gpa. This assignment I am currently working on is to write a function that calls on the previous one to see whether a student makes the deans list. I just figured I can turn the argument into a list of tuples which the helper function takes and it will return the proper value but it doesn't work and its getting frustrating.

Comment: @SeungsooIm: and where is your code?